# LINQ Query Problems with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a requirement to modify a function that uses a LINQ query to return a collection of data by adding an extra boolean for each item, so for simplicity I decided to change the return type to be a list of `KeyValuePairs`. However I have an error which I am unable to solve, or unfortunately understand.

The original version or the function is as follows:

```
Private Function GetSelectedExtractors() As List(Of ExtractionMapping)

    Return _extractionSelections _
        .SelectMany(Function(x) x.ExtractionRoutineSelection) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Selected) _
        .Select(Function(x) x.ExtractionMapping)

End Function
```

The new version, with the error, is below:

```
Private Function GetSelectedExtractors() As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of ExtractionMapping, Boolean))

    Return _extractionSelections _
        .SelectMany(Function(x) x.ExtractionRoutineSelection) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Selected) _
        .Select(Function(x) New KeyValuePair(Of ExtractionMapping, Boolean) _
                     (x.ExtractionMapping, x.DeleteExistingInstances))

End Function
```

The error I receive is this:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these     arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of ExtractionRoutineSelection, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of ExtractionRoutineSelection, Integer, TResult)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of ExtractionRoutineSelection, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of ExtractionRoutineSelection, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': 'DeleteExistingInstances' is not a member of 'Domain.ProductionWizard.ExtractionRoutineSelection'.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of ExtractionRoutineSelection, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
```

I have done plenty of LINQ queries in C#, but not that many in VB so it could well be my understanding of the syntax. I have tried several variations without success, I can convert it into an anonymous type as opposed to a `KeyValuePair`, but that's not suitable for this implementation.

Any solutions or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `x.DeleteExistingInstances` is invalid:

```
'DeleteExistingInstances' is not a member of Domain.ProductionWizard.ExtractionRoutineSelection'
```

Fix that and it should work as you want.

However, I would suggest using [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) instead of `KeyValuePair`:

```
Private Function GetSelectedExtractors() As List(Of Tuple(Of ExtractionMapping, Boolean))

    Return _extractionSelections _
        .SelectMany(Function(x) x.ExtractionRoutineSelection) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Selected) _
        .Select(Function(x) Tuple.Create(x.ExtractionMapping, x.DeleteExistingInstances))
        .ToList()

End Function
```

Comment: The `x.DeleteExistingInstances` was a typo when writing the question! However, in fixing that I noticed that I had actually added the property in question on the wrong class! I feel like a fool! On the other hand, why would you choose a Tuple in this case? I do use Tuples, but usually when I have more than two objects in the output. Just interested in your opinion.

Comment: Because it does not look like there was real *key-value* relationship between your data. Just two values, where neither first nor second is a key. Of course - you have a bigger picture so maybe it really is *key-value*. I don't see it that way by only that method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess I have just been using `KeyValuePair`s for such a long time I keep forgetting that `Tuple`s can be used for many situations like this!